# spfx webpart Canvas size on Modern Page

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I've created an spfx webpart using the react-office-ui-fabric DetailsList. It works fine, but the details list is quite wide. On a modern page the framework is rendeing my webpart in a div that is set to max-width 1280ox which causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear.
[image]

It seems to do that for all webparts. 
Is there a way to override the max-width on a modern page? Works fine on a classic page/

Comment: Since you say it works on Classic, do you mean your CSS (injected via your SPFx WebPart) is not applied?

Comment: No, I am saying that Modern pages display webparts in a div with the max-width set to 1280 px.

Comment: Hey russell, Did you got any solution for this issue. I am facing same issue

Comment: No, I never did. sorry

Comment: But the Preview button on the new workbench works well, so I dont really need it anymore

Answer (score 2):

I have added the following styles in my `module.scss` file and it worked perfectly for me.

```
 :global {
      #workbenchPageContent, .CanvasComponent.LCS .CanvasZone {
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you increase CSS Specificity you can set your own max-width:

```
.Canvas.Canvas{
    max-width:initial;
}
```

or

```
.Canvas.Canvas{
    max-width:100vw;
}
```

See: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Is it good idea to increase the canvas size to 180 vh? from the webpart css

Answer (score 0):

you could use a script Editor for modern pages form bitalus.com in example and input:

```
<style>
   .Canvas{
       max-width:100% !important;
   }
</style>
```

this is working for me like a cham!